# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') happened when I try to run "npm run compile"

Tags: javascript, npm, parcel

\snabbdom\node_modules\ttypescript\lib\loadTypescript.js:29
var _e = ts.versionMajorMinor.split('.'), major = _e[0], minor = _e[1];
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

snabbdom version is 2.1.0

Why did this happened and how to solve it ?

Comment: Seems like malformed `package.json` or `tsconfig`

Comment: Got the same issue, suddenly, on a project that hasn't change since it last built

Comment: same and still no clue

Answer (score 1):

For me, switching from `node v16.19.0` to `node v14.21.2` helped.

Basically the project I built using ttypescript is like 3 years old and was developed with `node v12` or smth.
So yeah, `node v14` helped.

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar problem, and after updating the `ttypescript` package to the latest version the problem also resolved.
Hope it will help to solve your issue.